# Single Digit Day and Month in BigQuery Data Transfer Service

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery, dts

When using run BigQuery Data Transfer Service to ingest data from S3, I needed to use run-time parameters to provide the current month and day in the URI.

Example: `s3://bucket/year=2022/month=6/day=6/*.json`

I was unable to find single digit month. Looks like we have the single digit day yet the preceding space makes it not usable. Please refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements)

Do we have any single-digit month and day format without any preceding space where we can use on URI path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(update)
I'm not sure below format string will work as same in DTS run-time parameter, but I think you can try this at least.  I've added some format specifiers to remove preceding space.

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('year=%Y/month=%_-m/day=%-e', '2022-06-06') AS uri_date;
```

[image]

---

`%m` seems to cover the single digit of month.

```sql
SELECT PARSE_DATE('year=%Y/month=%m/day=%e', 'year=2022/month=6/day=6') AS uri_date;
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is an implicit conversion here. Yet my goal is to use a format expression in URI path with run_time|format_exp.  Please see following example:    s3://bucket/month={run_time|“%m”}, returns s3//bucket/month=06. I would like this month to be “6” here.

Comment: I'm not sure it will be helpful, but kindly check my update.

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger! Using %_-m and %-e solved the issue!